# How do I register a user

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo, alert

I currently have the following code: If that email is already registered then the user will be promoted with a message. However if the email is not already registered then they can register. When I run this code and register a user who has not already registered, they are still getting the alert that username already exists. I think it may be something with the brackets!

```
<?php

include ("dbConnect.php");
require 'libPassword.php';

function filter_email_header($email){
  return preg_replace('/[\0\n\r\|\!\/\<\>\^\$\%\*\&]+/','',$email);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $forename = $_POST['forename'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $medical_conditions = $_POST['medical_conditions'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $last_login = date("Y-n-d");




    $dbQuery=$db->prepare("SELECT email FROM customer where email > 0");
            $dbParams = array('email'=>$email);
            $dbQuery->execute($dbParams);
            if ($dbQuery) {
                $message = "username already exists";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
            }//if
            else{

    $hashPassword = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));

      if($dbQuery->rowCount()==0){
          $dbQuery=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO customer (forename, surname, telephone, address, medical_conditions, dob, email, password) VALUES (:forename, :surname, :telephone, :address, :medical_conditions, :dob, :email, :hashPassword)");
            $dbParams = array('forename'=>$forename,'surname'=>$surname, 'telephone'=>$telephone, 'address'=>$address,'medical_conditions'=>$medical_conditions, 'dob'=>$dob, 'email'=>$email, 'hashPassword'=>$hashPassword);
            $dbQuery->execute($dbParams);
            if($dbQuery) {


                header("Location: myProfile.php");
            }//if

        }//if
        else{
                echo('Please fill out all fields marked with *');
            }//else2
            }//else1

if(isset($email)){
  $sender='jess@gymmembership.com';
  $email = filter_email_header($email);
  $headers = "From:". $sender;
  $to      = $email; // Send email to our user
  $subject = 'Signup | Verification'; // Give the email a subject 
  $message = '

Thanks for signing up!
Here is your login details:

------------------------
Your email: '.$email.'
Password: '.$password.'
------------------------

You can now login to your account:


'; // Our message above including the link

$headers = 'From:gymmanagementsystem' . "\r\n"; // Set from headers
//mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send our email
$sent=mail($to, $subject, $message, $email);
    }}
?>
```

Comment: `"SELECT password FROM customer where email = :email"` should fetch the password of the user, that you can use to perform `password_verify` on. If no row is returned, the email adres is invalid. When a user attempts to register, verify the email does not exist in the db yet.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you are checking if the query executed and not check whether or not you actually got a match. Check if your number of row are > 0.

```
if ($dbQuery) {
    $message = "username already exists";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}
```

Also pretty sure you might actually want to compare to an email like so.

```
"SELECT email FROM customer where email = :email"
```

I also wouldn't replace the unwanted character in the email it could be that they type "!" instead of "@" by accident and your email wouldn't be valid. I would suggest notifying that the email isn't valid and for what reason.